# Googlebot ignore my new site

Tags: seo, google, robots.txt, googlebot, web-crawlers

I have the following situation: I had a blog (made using Joomla) that in some month was pretty indexed by Google.

For some technical problem I have delete it and I have newly created using WordPress (so it is a different site, only the URL it is the same) and I have reinserted manually all the articles.

Looking at my statistics I can see that there are many visitors that try to visit the old page (that now don't exist in the new site that have a different structure)

The problems are the following one: it seems to me that Google Bot try to visit only the old pages (that don't exist) but it is ignoring the new pages of the new site (consequently not the indexes)

Some day ago, I find that I have enabled the settings to deter search engines to index your site so I have change it and now, in theory, Google have to visit these pages and index it...

Why this is not happening? How can I solve it?

**REQUIRED INFORMATIONS:**

The URL of my site is: http://www.scorejava.com/

and this is my **robots.txt** content:

```
# If the Joomla site is installed within a folder such as at
# e.g. www.example.com/joomla/ the robots.txt file MUST be
# moved to the site root at e.g. www.example.com/robots.txt
# AND the joomla folder name MUST be prefixed to the disallowed
# path, e.g. the Disallow rule for the /administrator/ folder
# MUST be changed to read Disallow: /joomla/administrator/
#
# For more information about the robots.txt standard, see:
# http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html
#
# For syntax checking, see:
# http://www.sxw.org.uk/computing/robots/check.html

User-agent: *
Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /cli/
Disallow: /components/
Disallow: /images/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /installation/
Disallow: /language/
Disallow: /libraries/
Disallow: /logs/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /plugins/
Disallow: /templates/
Disallow: /tmp/
```

The strange think is that in the robots.txt comment makes reference to Joomla and WordPress...maybe is still use the old robots.txt file of the previous website (that was in the same space)?

Comment: Please share your URL and robots.txt.

Comment: Why don't you redirect from the old posts to the new ones with a 302 redirect?

Comment: ok, I have edited the original post inserting the required details

Comment: Your using Joomla's Robot.txt, while this isn't a problem you should use a wordpress one.. The problem with Google is that you haven't waited long enough... These changes takes, weeks to months. Also the question is duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following Wordpress plugins which might help you:

- [True Google 404](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/true-google404/) - Keeps track of 404 errors and tries to resolve the ones that it can through site search
- [Custom Permalinks](http://atastypixel.com/blog/wordpress/plugins/custom-permalinks/) - Lets you choose the URLs for your pages (you could rename the URLs to what they used to be under Joomla)
- [Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin](http://www.fischercreativemedia.com/wordpress-plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) - Allows you specify other redirects from within the wordpress admin pages.
- [MDR Webmaster Tools](http://mattrude.com/projects/mdr-webmaster-tools/) - Lets you verify your site with [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) so you can log in there and see problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [301 redirect](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) from old pages to new ones in order to giving access to robots and visitors to your articles from outside of your website.

Indeed, If a website put a link to one of your article and you don't redirect old URL to new one, visitor falls into a 404 error page and bots too (notification by Google in Google Webmaster Tools). With 301 redirect, visitor can access to the article. Moreover, robots like Googlebot will transfer PR of your old pages to the new ones and you can get back your positions in search engines index.

It's a win-win solution: visitors and SEO.

Comment: the problem is that the architecture of the new site is different from the old site and some articles don't exist in the new version or have different name

Comment: You need to redirect each page one by one.

Comment: mmm this is a very hard work...if I wait some weeks is it possible that Google delete the old links from its SERP and begin di index the new inserted articles?

Comment: Try to adapt old architecture to the new one with generic rules for your 301 redirects. Without redirects, Google will delete old URLs by itself but your visitors from outside are lost (404 pages) and you loose PR of your webpages.